# PHP Search function breaks my website

Tags: php, mysql, function, search, full-text-search

**I'm trying to implement a search function in my website.**
The search bar would be accessed in a modal screen from the navigatio bar
and it is used to search and retrieve records from a mySQL table.

The actual search function is being called forth from an external file through the use of PHP's require function along with all other common functions that make my site work. **The problem is that by simply adding this function, my ceases to show - it's nothing but white blankness.**

**Here is the search function right here** (currently WIP)...

```
function search_requests {
        global $db;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM requests ";
        $sql .= "WHERE title LIKE '%".$query."%'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        confirm_result_set($result);
        return $result;
    }
```

I am sure this alone is causing my site to crash because whenever I delete it, the site starts working again.

To give you some more context over how this works, **here is some code from the webpage that is supposed to show the records retrieved through the search function.**

```
$query = $_GET['searchby'];
$request_set = search_requests();
```

And here is the **code from the PHP file that houses the search modal menu**, which is also retrieved through a require function.

```
<form class="form-signin" action="search.php" method="get">
   <input type="search" name="searchby" value="" placeholder="Ask a question...">
   <input type="submit" value="Ask">
</form>
```

**So where have I gone wrong?**
Please someone tell me.

Comment: change `function search_requests{` to this `function search_requests (){`

Comment: you should pass the query in $query in search_requests () and get in afunction  call

Comment: It worked. Thank you. I have a very bad habit of leaving out something as small and simple like that without even noticing.

Comment: I would stop using `global` and pass in the database connection as a parameter anyway.

Comment: The following: `$sql .= "WHERE title LIKE '%".$query."%'";` can be written as: `$sql .= "WHERE title LIKE '%$query%'";`, variables expand inside double-quotes. Please take some time learning how to debug php code. Start by adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of  your  script, what does it output? The solution to your question is simple: ***Just provide an argument to your function.***

Answer (score 0):

You should add parenthesis `()` while defining a function as the function named `demo_func()`

```
      function search_requests($query) {        
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM requests ";
        $sql .= "WHERE title LIKE '%".$query."%'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        confirm_result_set($result);
        return $result;
    } 

$query = $_GET['searchby'];
$request_set = search_requests($query); //pass $query in a function call
```

Please read this article https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_functions.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your should be passing value in your calling function :

```
$query = $_GET['searchby'];
$request_set = search_requests($query);
```

Then You should add parenthesis () while defining a function and passing value:

```
function search_requests($query) { 
  //do
}
```